# Truecrypt Cloned to Multiple USB

Tags: truecrypt

We're using Truecrypt on an 8Gb USB key plugged into a Windows 7 machine. We have 2 other identical keys that we want to replicate that volume to. Is there an easier way than just copying the container over every morning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mount each TC container and then use **robocopy**, a built-in command line tool, to copy over changed files. Use the **/MIR** command line switch to make an identical copy, including deleting files on the target that have been deleted from the source.

In a bacth file, you could mount both truecrypt volumes and then use robocopy to transfer changed files.

```
rem mount source as s:, target at t:
TrueCrypt.exe /v e:\source.tc /ls /q /c
TrueCrypt.exe /v f:\target.tc /lt /q /c

rem copy the files
robocopy.exe s:\ t:\ * /mir

rem dismount TC volumes
TrueCrypt.exe /d s:
TrueCrypt.exe /d t:
```